# How to customize keyboard input and format?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've upgraded from `material-ui-pickers 2.x` to `@material-ui/pickers 3.x` (both with `@date-io/moment`). And now I'm struggling with the keyboard input and format.

With version `2.x` I used `format="D.M.YYYY"`. The user was able to type for example `1.1.2000` or `04.08.2000` or `12.12.2000`.

But with version `3.x` the input only strictly allows `1.1.2000`. It's not possible to have 2-digit day or month. Though I changed to `format="DD.MM.YYYY"`, but now it's impossible to input 1-digit day or month without a leading zero. E.g. typing `1.1.2000` results in `11.20.00`.

How can I achieve one (or both) of the following behaviors?

1. User can input whatever he wants, including characters (same behavior as with version `2.x`). Or:
2. Listen for `.` input and then jump to the next input section. I.e. User types `1.2.2000` and it will set `1` for day, then jump to the month section, because user pressed `.` key, then set `2` for month, then jump to year section, because user pressed `.` and then set `2000` for year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a kinda hacky solution for case 1 using `refuse` and `rifmFormatter`:

```
<KeyboardDatePicker
    refuse={/[^\d\.]+/gi}
    rifmFormatter={value => value.replace(/[^\d\.]+/gi, '')}
    format={"D.M.YYYY"}
    ...
/>
```

This will only allow digits and dot as input in any order, and removes input masking.

Not the optimal solution, but way better than before.